# Startup code for new layout or new drawable is not coming

Tags: android, xml, layout

I know this sounds silly but whenever I try to add new layout or new drawable or any other new file I end up getting blank xml file. I don't know why this is happening. Help me, I am a beginner I need those startup code to get going.
Below is the screenshot which shows how it goes after creating a new xml [image]file.

Comment: try to clean the project, again build it and run.

Comment: this is happening in every project @HemantParmar

Comment: just do one thing click on file/Invalidate Cashes/Restart.

Comment: nothing happened. it is still creating blank xml files

Comment: Check  IDE Errors. It's below the Gradle Console and a red '!' symbol.

Comment: just noticed my sample code in File->Editor->Files and code templates are empty for every section. looks like I have to reinstall.